# what happens if I call new in c++, but the heap is out of memory?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, new-operator

I'm curious to know what happens when heap memory is full and we call `new` operator in `c++` or `malloc` in `c`? Is there any way to clear the whole heap memory?

Comment: Please perform _research_ before asking questions.

Comment: If you call `melloc` in c, you''l simply end up with a compiler error. In case you're calling `malloc` it will return `NULL` if you're out of memory. And no, there's no way _"to clear the whole heap memory"_

Comment: These are two questions in one. Please don't do that but address them separately. The case being with some reasonable effort you would have had the answers to both.

Comment: @JensGustedt, there are tree questions, to be precise.

Comment: @SergeyA: To be precise, there are no trees on the internet.

Comment: No green ones.  There are red and black trees.

Comment: @Martin Actually, tree nodes are often "marked" green during some common tree operations, e.g. http://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/crabbe/SI321/current/red-black/red-black.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ["New and delete (C++)" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B)):

> **If not enough memory is available in the free store for an object of type `T`, the `new` request indicates failure by throwing an exception of type `std::bad_alloc`.** This removes the need to explicitly check the result of an allocation.

Comment: Just to add, you can have the `nothrow` version

Comment: `int main() { new int[10000000000]; }` well that was easy. Are you asking whether I've ever experienced a process's memory space being paged into swap? Yes, yes I have.